# In angular dart, how do you make up/down arrow keys navigate through a list?

Tags: angular-dart

Using angular dart, I have a material dialog with a basic list on it. When the dialog shows I want the end user to be able to navigate the list with the arrow keys (up/down).

```
<modal *ngIf="visible" [visible]="visible">
    <material-dialog headered class="headered-dialog">
        <div header>
            <h1>List Demo</h1>
        </div>

        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
            <div class="list-body form-control">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
                        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>

    </material-dialog>
</modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

package:angular_components provide a `MaterialListComponent` and `FocusListDirective` that support up/down navigation

https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_list

You can use them together as follow

```html
<material-list focusList>
  <material-list-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </material-list-item>
</material-list>
```

Never tried but you should also be able to use the `FocusListDirective` on any element.

```html
<ul focusList>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great and I got it to work except for 2 issues. When the list loses focus, the selected item highlight goes away. This may just be how this control works. The other thing is that when I navigate via keyboard, I'm not getting the (trigger) event that I get when I click on an item in the list. There is probably another event I need and I'll keep searching for that.